# jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field , not marked as ignorable

Tags: android, json, jackson

I am fetching json data by hitting url .After that I used Json parsing it is working fine and got the result and showing in android application.But this time I tried jackson parser for fast parsing.I got this error.please help me

Code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); jacksonObj=mapper.readValue(jsonResponse,ContactPojo.class);
```

pojo:

```
public class ContactPojo {

    String name,email,gender,mobileno;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getMobileno() {
        return mobileno;
    }

    public void setMobileno(String mobileno) {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

}
```

error:

```
02-15 17:20:20.060: W/System.err(3983): org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "contacts" (Class com.example.sampleuserlogin.ContactPojo), not marked as ignorable
02-15 17:20:20.060: W/System.err(3983):  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4155f0b8; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.example.sampleuserlogin.ContactPojo["contacts"])
02-15 17:20:20.065: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
02-15 17:20:20.065: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
02-15 17:20:20.070: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
02-15 17:20:20.070: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1361)
02-15 17:20:20.075: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
02-15 17:20:20.075: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
02-15 17:20:20.080: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
02-15 17:20:20.085: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
02-15 17:20:20.085: W/System.err(3983):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
02-15 17:20:20.085: W/System.err(3983):     at com.example.sampleuserlogin.JsonParser.jsonParser(JsonParser.java:50)
02-15 17:20:20.090: W/System.err(3983):     at com.example.sampleuserlogin.RetrieveLogindata$Response.onPostExecute(RetrieveLogindata.java:69)
02-15 17:20:20.095: W/System.err(3983):     at com.example.sampleuserlogin.RetrieveLogindata$Response.onPostExecute(RetrieveLogindata.java:1)
02-15 17:20:20.095: W/System.err(3983):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
02-15 17:20:20.095: W/System.err(3983):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
02-15 17:20:20.095: W/System.err(3983):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
02-15 17:20:20.095: W/System.err(3983):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 17:20:20.100: W/System.err(3983):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 17:20:20.100: W/System.err(3983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
02-15 17:20:20.100: W/System.err(3983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 17:20:20.100: W/System.err(3983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 17:20:20.100: W/System.err(3983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-15 17:20:20.100: W/System.err(3983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-15 17:20:20.105: W/System.err(3983):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

json:

```
{

     "contacts": [

         {

                 "id": "c200",

                 "name": "sai ram",

                 "email": "sai@gmail.com",

                 "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",

                 "gender" : "male",

                 "phone": {

                     "mobile": "+91 0000000000",

                     "home": "00 000000",

                     "office": "00 000000"

                 }

         },

         {

                 "id": "c201",

                 "name": "Johnny Depp",

                 "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",

                 "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",

                 "gender" : "male",

                 "phone": {

                     "mobile": "+91 0000000000",

                     "home": "00 000000",

                     "office": "00 000000"

                 }

         }
]}
```

Comment: your `ContactPojo` class is not root in json ... your json is an object with property contacts which is array of your pojo please read some tutorials before asking question here

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you have a few issues.

E.g.

You need a wrapper

```
public class Contacts {
   public List<ContactPojo> contacts;
}
```

Few other issues

```
public class ContactPojo {
    Phone phone;
}

public class Phone {
     String mobile;
     String home;
     String office;
}
```